# How to create slider effect looking which flies across the page during transition?

Tags: slider, helper

I have been doing research to find different types of slider and I still can't find anything similar to the one on this website:

http://www.addiction.com.tw/

At this website at second page there is a slider which, during transition, looks like it flies across the page.

I would like to create a similar slider, anyone can help?

Comment: Did you mean this widget? http://bxslider.com

Comment: Provide some pictures instead only the link

Answer (score 0):

The following are all of addiction.com.tw plugins:

```
jquery.min.js
jquery.scroll.events.js
jquery.touchSwipe.js
detectmobilebrowser.c.js
jquery.scrollTo-min.js
jquery.localscroll-min.js
easySlider1.7.c.js
jquery.shadowbox.js
jquery.bxSlider.min.js
jquery.fancybox.js
```

Every script is initiated here:

http://www.addiction.com.tw/js/site.js

The exception is located at the `<head>`:

```
<script>
Shadowbox.init();

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#inline").fancybox({ 
        'hideOnContentClick': false,
        'overlayOpacity': 0.85}).click();
});
</script>
```

**Note:** Although bxSlider is loaded, I don't see it actually being used. The site's main form of navigation is a special type of scrolling called parallax. I think the easySlider plugin is responsible for that.

This site does not rely on a cookie cutter like Word-Press and doesn't have any major framework like Bootstrap. It's very clean (with the exception of bxSlider being unused). The parallax scrolling might be written from scratch instead of using a plugin. See this: http://andyshora.com/parallax.html

If your'e familiar with HTML, CSS, JS/jQuery this is a good site to learn from.

Comment: But without the special type of scrolling called parallax, the slider can't be created?

Comment: It can of course but it won't have that background sliding effect you probably want. Try using easySlider, there are other plugins that have parallax built in. I think the creator of this site used a combo of the plugins PLUS the parallax scrolling procedure detailed in the previously mentioned site (andyshora.com)